# While loop not continuing after an if statement in C

Tags: c

Ok so the problem I currently have is that the while loop doesn't continue after the first if statement if the condition of typing in "-c" as the 5th argument isn't met.

If -c is typed in it continues perfectly as normal. It's probably a rookie mistake but I can't figure out why it doesn't continue even if the condition isn't met. Can provide more details if required.

```
 while(fscanf(file, "%s", word) != EOF)
    {
        if (strcmp(argv[5], "-c") == 0);
            {
            // Convert word to lowercase
            strlwr(word);
            }

       //Remove last punctuation character
        len = strlen(word);
        if (ispunct(word[len - 1]))
            word[len - 1] = '\0';

        //Check if word exists in list of all distinct words
        unique = 1;
        for (i=0; i<index && unique; i++)
        {
            if(strcmp(words[i], word) == 0)
                unique = 0;
        }

        //If word is unique then add it to distinct words list
        //And increment index. Otherwise increment occurrence
        // count of current word.
        if(unique)
        {
            strcpy(words[index], word);
            counter[index]++;

            index++;
        }

        else
        {
            counter[i - 1]++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `if (strcmp(argv[5], "-c") == 0);` ---> `if (strcmp(argv[5], "-c") == 0)` as `;` at the end of `if` statement make it as dummy & `strlwr(word);` will execute always whether condition is true or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is wrong in two ways:

```
if (strcmp(argv[5], "-c") == 0);
```

First, you’re ending the `if` with a semicolon, so it tests whether the
fifth argument is `"-c"`, but then it runs the next block either way.

If you’re not typing `-c` as the fifth argument, you probably only have
four arguments, in which case the fifth argument would be `NULL`. (Or
you might have fewer than four, in which case there is no fifth argument
at all.) Passing `NULL` to `strcmp` is undefined behavior. So, you need
to check that `argv >= 5` before testing `argv[5]`.

Answer (score 0):

a rule of thumbs is 1 can be used as boolean true and 0 as false.

So just use some other number than 1 and 0 or check the condition with something else like if `unique == 3/any;`

Here's a code that will be useful to understand why the loop is not working.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

int i;

    printf("Hi, Enter any int : 1 or 0.\n");

scanf("%d",&i);

if(i){
    printf("Hi, see Without 0 it works.");
}
return 0;
}
```